# Java Reflection parameter type matching, how-to handle interfaces instead classes

Tags: java, reflection

Given a class Something with a constructor `public Something(List<String> l)`, I would like to use `klass.getConstructor(parameterTypes)` where `parameterTypes[0]` is the class `java.util.ArrayList` (because I need to "match" a given specific instance) and not the interface java.util.List.

This doesn't work (NoSuchMethodException), because Java Reflection appears to need an EXACT type class match.  What is the best way around this?

Answer (score 7):

Might be overkill, and admittedly could pick up too many constructors:

```
Constructor[] constructors = klass.getConstructors();
for(Constructor constructor:constructors) {
      Class<?>[] params = constructor.getParameterTypes();
      if(params.length == 1 && params[0].isAssignableFrom(ArrayList.class) {
          //Yep could be the one you want.
      }
}
```

Comment: Yes of course indeed; thank you very much. Done in https://github.com/vorburger/vorburgers-blueprints/blob/master/appviewsnflows-core/src/main/java/ch/vorburger/appviewsnflows/util/ReflectionUtil.java

FTR java.beans.ReflectionUtils has stuff like that as well, but is not public; http://code.google.com/p/reflectutils/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/azeckoski/reflectutils/ConstructorUtils.java#699 of http://code.google.com/p/reflectutils/ has an even better version.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection only will find methods that are actually declared. If the constructor is declared to take `List`, that's the only constructor there is. There's no such concept as 'matching a specific instance' when using reflection. If you had *two* constructors, one taking `List` and one taking `ArrayList`, then you could grab either one via `getConstructor`.

I don't see why you think you need this. If you call `newInstance`, and then you use `getConstructor` on the declared `List` type, then you can pass it an instance of `ArrayList`.

Comment: uhm, well I do need it ;) The answer above was helpful.

Comment: `Class.getMethod(Class...)` will find "matching methods" much like the compiler.  So reflection is not completely impotent.  I'm still confused why Sun decided to make `getMethod(..)` use parameter matching, but `getConstructor(..)` won't.